# SignalR Core - Check connection state from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, connection, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` to open a connection from my WebAPI project to connect and call methods in my SignalR Hub project. These are separate projects hosted on separate servers.

How do I check whether the connection has been started, so I don't try to start it twice?

I connect from WebAPI using the following code:

```
public class ChatApi
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public ChatApi()
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder();
        _connection = connection.WithUrl("https://localhost:44302/chathub").Build();
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(Msg model)
    {
        await _connection.StartAsync();
        await _connection.SendAsync("Send", model);
    }
}
```

Since my WebAPI will be calling into SignalR quite a bit, I want to create the single connection between WebAPI and SignalR and not close/open the connection each time. At the moment I create the `ChatApi` class as a singleton and initialize the hub connection in the constructor.

How would I check if the connection is started before calling `await _connection.StartAsync();`?

Using: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` v1.0.0-preview1-final

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client v1.1.0+

There is a `State` property on `HubConnection`.

```cs
public class ChatApi
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public ChatApi()
    {
        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44302/chathub")
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task StartIfNeededAsync()
    {
        if (_connection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
        {
            await _connection.StartAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(Msg model)
    {
        await StartIfNeededAsync();
        await _connection.SendAsync("Send", model);
    }
}
```

References:

- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [aspnet/SignalR/pull/2204](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/2204)
- [dotnet/aspnetcore@7625bbc](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/7625bbcb6c6fc04faae2e92ffbb9114e23763f2a)

## Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client < v1.1.0

*(At the time of this writing, the latest version was 1.0.0-preview2-final.)*

There is no `ConnectionState` property.

You need to track the state yourself, by subscribing to the `Closed` event on `HubConnection`.

```
public class ChatApi
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    private ConnectionState _connectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;

    public ChatApi()
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder();
        _connection = connection.WithUrl("https://localhost:44302/chathub").Build();

        // Subscribe to event
        _connection.Closed += (ex) =>
        {
            if (ex == null)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Connection terminated");
                _connectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Connection terminated with error: {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
                _connectionState = ConnectionState.Faulted;
            }
        };
    }

    public async Task StartIfNeededAsync()
    {
        if (_connectionState == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            await _connection.StartAsync();
            _connectionState = ConnectionState.Connected;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Connection.Start Failed: {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
            _connectionState = ConnectionState.Faulted;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private enum ConnectionState
    {
        Connected,
        Disconnected,
        Faulted
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task SendMessage(Msg model)
{
    await StartIfNeededAsync();
    await _connection.SendAsync("Send", model);
}
```

References:

- [aspnet/SignalR/blob/1fc282a/benchmarkapps/Crankier/Client.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/1fc282acb87874daf6996b6893c19c51d9285814/benchmarkapps/Crankier/Client.cs)
- [aspnet/SignalR/issues/2127](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2127) (opened 8 days after this answer)

Comment: @Seabizkit Yes, I've updated the answer for newer versions.

Comment: thanks! , don't you want to write the singleton class now that everyone is wanting hehe, which wraps a retry policy.... ;-) thanks for the update tho..

Comment: It's out of scope for this question and there's a decent sample implementation in the linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 2.1 at least, you can check the `State` property of your HubConnection:

```
if (_connection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
        await _connection.StartAsync();
}
```